# Set the value of uncheck jquery checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am new to javascript, html and jquery. I would really appreciate any help or suggestion thanks in advance. I am trying to set the value of jquery checkbox to No if uncheck I adden an html code hidden with the same name of my jquery checkbox before my jquery checkbox

```
<input type="hidden" name="c1" value="No" />
```

actually it saving No if uncheck however if it is checked it saving as Yes;No

my jquesry check box

```
<input grouping="" id="c1" name="c1" type="checkbox" value="Yes"    />
```

Comment: do you have 2 inputs with the same `name` attribute? that wont work

Comment: I only have one checkbox but did create <input type="hidden" name="c1" value="No" /> and it saving no if the checkbox is uncheck however storing and displaying Yes;No if check box is checked

Comment: You cannot do this using plain HTML. An unchecked checkbox provides no value. The alternative is to do as you have done, by creating a text input with the same name, but then you will have to work with both values.

Comment: exactly. if the checkbox isnt checked, the value wont be submitted. having 2 inputs with the same name doesnt make sense in this case. use jquery or remove one checkbox

Comment: I also used this <script>
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
  $(this).val(this.checked ? "Yes" : "No");
})
</script>

Comment: I want to set like if check box Yes is uncheck then it will store No nut Null but when I used that code nothing happened just storing null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#c1").change(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  $("input[type=hidden][name=" + name + "]").val(($(this).is(":checked") ? "Yes" : "No"));
  console.log($("input[type=hidden][name=" + name + "]").val());
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#c1").change(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  $("input[type=hidden][name=" + name + "]").val(($(this).is(":checked") ? "Yes" : "No"));
  console.log($("input[type=hidden][name=" + name + "]").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="c1" value="No" />
<input grouping="" id="c1" name="c1" type="checkbox" value="Yes" />
```

Comment: If your using this code, it should switch between yes and no

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM

```
    if($("#c1").checked)
     $("#c1").value = "yes";
    else
     $("#c1").value = "no";
```

checked return true if checked or false

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript :

```
<input onchange="chkboxHandler()" id="c1" name="c1" type="checkbox" value="Yes" checked/>
```

On value change of checkbox we call the function bellow

```
<script>
        function chkboxHandler() {
          var chkbox = document.querySelector("input#c1")
          if (chkbox.checked) {
            chkbox.value = "Yes"
          } else {
            chkbox.value = "No"
          }
        }
</script>
```

Hoping you have your answer